# Spring Security - SPA OpenID Implicit flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, single-page-application, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect

We have implemented an SPA (**Angular 5 with angular-auth-oidc**) which requests an **id_token** and an **access_token** to from an OpenID Connect provider (for the moment we are testing with google), and then sends the **id_token** to the back-end (a **REST API using Spring Boot 5**)

My questions are:

1. what is the approach to send the access_token instead of the **id_token** ?
2. Once I am able to validate the **access_token**, how can I request another **access_token** and **refresh_token** ?
3. Does Spring Security provides a store (in memory) to keep temporarily the **access_token** and the **refresh_token** ?

I used the `@EnableResourceServer` to validate the **id_token** (jwt) and it works, but when I send the access_token (not a jwt), I get an exception, such as : `Invalid characters (CR/LF) in header WWW-Authenticate`.